# find command - get base name only - NOT with basename command / NOT with printf

Tags: bash, shell, find

Is there any way to get the `basename` in the command `find`?

What I **don't** need:

- `find /dir1 -type f -printf "%f\n"`
- `find /dir1 -type f -exec basename {} \;`

Why you may ask? Because I need to continue using the `found file`. I basically want something like this:

```bash
find . -type f -exec find /home -type l -name "*{}*" \;
```

And it uses `./file1`, not `file1` as the agrument for `-name`.

---

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `find /dir1 -type f -printf "%f\n"` works well, what's the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by _I need to continue using the found file_? If you need the basename **and** the abs path as well, just pipe the abs path into a program of your choice and do the logic there. Or don't use `find` but an explicit loop (`for f in /dir1/**`) with _globstar_ turned on. Of course you have then to handle testing for _plain file_ by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to forward it to another evaluator. There is no way to do that in `find`.

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\0' |
    xargs -r0I{} find /home -type l -name '*{}*'
```

This answers your question about trying to merge the functionality of `%f` and `-exec find` and is based on your example but your example injects raw filenames as `-name` patterns so avoid that and look at other solutions instead.

Comment: @GillesQuenot Same as `-I{}`. There's really no reason to deprecate it.

Comment: This is mostly OK (upvoted), but it can break if you've got filenames that contain `find ... -name` pattern characters.  For instance, if I run `touch '*'` and run it I get a list of *all* symlinks under `/home`.

Comment: @pjh Right I missed that. It has to be shell escaped or maybe just use a shell with a while loop.

Comment: @konsolebox this is now deprecated from `find`. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Spawn a shell and make the second call to find from there

```
find /dir1 -type f -exec sh -c '
for p; do
  find /dir2 -type l -name "*${p##*/}*"
done' sh {} +
```

If your files may contain special characters in their names (like `[`, `?`, etc.), you may want to escape them like this to avoid false positives

```
find /dir1 -type f -exec sh -c '
for p; do
  esc=$(printf "%sx\n" "${p##*/}" | sed "s/[?*[\]/\\\&/g")
  esc=${esc%x}
  find /dir2 -type l -name "*$esc*"
done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Bash version 4.3 or later, try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob globstar nullglob
for path in ./**; do
    [[ -L $path ]] && continue
    [[ -f $path ]] || continue
    base=${path##*/}
    for path2 in /home/**/*"$base"*; do
        [[ -L $path2 ]] && printf '%s\n' "$path2"
    done
done
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` shows such files by default.
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.  `globstar` was introduced in Bash 4.0, but it was dangerous to use before Bash 4.3 (2014) because it followed symlinks when looking for matches.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${path##*/}`.  That always works, even in some rare cases where `$(basename "$path")` doesn't.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of `echo` to output the found paths.
- This solution works correctly if you've got files that contain pattern characters (`?`, `*`, `[`, `]`, `\`) in their names.

Answer (score 0):

Simply spawn a `bash` shell:

```
find /dir1 -type f -exec bash -c '
    base=$(basename "$1")
    echo "$base"
    do_something_else "$base"
' bash {} \;
```

`$1` in the `bash` part is each file filtered by `find`.